# JIT compiler and anonymous inner classes

Tags: java, optimization, compiler-construction

The callback functions by anonymous class is a common approach when we use a framework or a library, so it is very useful to know if the JIT performs such kind optimizations.

I am wondering if the JIT compiler is smart enough to understand that them some code is executed every time and compile into native?

Comment: Could you explain that a bit more? The JIT compiler will create (and optimise) each anonymous inner class as it would with any other class.

Comment: JIT compiler responsibility is to translate the bytecode to the native language that the underlying execution platform understands. During this compilation, also adds performance counters to each block that translates. Every time the code block is executed the counter increased. If the counter reaches a threshold (typically 1500 invocations), the block is compiled permanently to native code. My question is if the JIT compiler understands that an method invocation from an anonymous class is actually call for the same block and increase the counter or supposes that it is a different call?

Comment: @mspapant Please explain what you mean by 'call for the same block'; how the JIT compiler would unambiguously identify it;  and what different semantics it would have that makes you think a JIT compiler would treat it any differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like any other piece of code, it will be compiled and optimized by the JIT compiler once it has been executed enough times (by default, 10000 with the Hotspot server VM, 1500 with the client VM), so the JIT has enough data to base its optimizations on.

Just because it's anonymous does not mean it's treated any different: it's still a class, with a name generated during the compilation (MyClass$1).

Comment: Probably you are right. Since the javac compiler "transforms" the anonymous classes to.. named MyClass$1 etc. there is not reason not to apply the same optimization as "regular" classes.

Comment: @mspapant There's no 'probably' about it. Frank is right. Why should the JIT or HotSpot care about the name of a class?

Comment: At that point, it's just bytecode anyway.